# Invariant cyclic subspace problem proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v, T(v),\ldots, T^{k-1} (v)$ be the basis of a $T$ invariant subspace of dimension $k$.

Show that if $T^m(v) =  0$, where $m>k-1$, then $T^k(v)= 0$, i.e. if the chain of transformations ever reaches zero, it will become zero 'latest' by the time it hits the $k$th iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The proof you desire will follow easily from the following exercise:

***Exercise 1***: Prove that if $T:V\to V$ is a nilpotent operator and $V$ is finite dimensional, then $T^{\dim V}=0$.

If you solve ***Exercise 1***, then notice that in the hypothesis of your question, $T$ defines a nilpotent operator on the $T$-invariant subspace of dimension $k$ that you've noted (i.e., the span of $v,Tv,\dots,T^{k-1}v$). Therefore, $T^k=0$ on this subspace, in particular $T^k(v)=0$ since $v$ is an element of this subspace.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any difficulties with solving ***Exercise 1*** and I'm happy to help.

Comment: We can use the fact that eigenvalues of a nilpotent transformation are all zeroes. Then we can use Cayley - Hamilton theorem. Right? Is there an alternative way?

Comment: @Isomorphism The proof I have in mind is via the filtration $\{0\}\subseteq \text{ker} T\subseteq \text{ker} T^2\subseteq\cdots\subseteq \text{ker} T^n=V$ where $n$ is such that $T^n=0$. Note that there can be at most $\text{dim} V$ distinct non-zero terms in this filtration so $T^{\dim V}=0$ ... Please let me know once you see this comment so I can delete it; it would probably be good for the OP to try ***Exercise 1*** independently before viewing any hints/solutions.

Comment: @Isomorphism (I suppose the proof via the Cayley-Hamilton theorem would be as follows: the minimal polynomial of $T$ has degree at most $\text{dim} V$ by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem and divides the polynomial $x^n$ where $n$ is such that $T^n=0$. Of course, any polynomial divisor of $x^n$ must itself be a power of $x$. Therefore, $T^{\dim V}=0$. If that's the proof that you have in mind, then that's certainly correct.)

Comment: Thanks for the other proof. I forgot the filtration trick.